# How can I get aggregated measures with continuous dates?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to display the total amount (as text) of a measure filtered by a continuous date filter (slider). I doesn't sound difficult but when I try this it looks like the result is not aggregated and the amount for each single day is displayed on top of the others, and it's obviously not what I want.
So how can I get Tableau to summarize the result as one summed value when I use continuous dates?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if its matters, but dates are discrete; and not continuous.

Comment: Not in this case, I made my date field continuous on purpose so that I can filter on a range of dates instead of a specific date and that I can use a slider.

Comment: I found a solution: http://community.tableau.com/thread/146843?tstart=0#333298 . The issue is coming from the Tableau/SSAS combination.